# MySQL : Dependent Sub Query with NOT IN in the WHERE clause is very slow

Tags: mysql, mysql-dependent-subquery

I am auditing user details from my application using open Id login .If a first time a user is login a OPEN ID we consider as signup . I am generating audit signin report using this details . Sample Table Data.

```
+---------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| USER_ID | PROVIDER | OPERATION | TIMESTAMP     |
+---------+----------+-----------+---------------+
|     120 | Google   | SIGN_UP   | 1347296347000 |
|     120 | Google   | SIGN_IN   | 1347296347000 |
|     121 | Yahoo    | SIGN_IN   | 1347296347000 |
|     122 | Yahoo    | SIGN_IN   | 1347296347000 |
|     120 | Google   | SIGN_UP   | 1347296347000 |
|     120 | FaceBook | SIGN_IN   | 1347296347000 |
+---------+----------+-----------+---------------+
```

In this table I want to exclude already **SIGN_UP** ed "**SIGN_IN**" ed user count  based on provider .

**Show Create table**

```
CREATE TABLE `signin_details` (
  `USER_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROVIDER` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OPERATION` char(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIMESTAMP` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I am using this query .

```
select 
  count(distinct(USER_ID)) as signin_count, 
  PROVIDER from signin_details s1 
where 
  s1.USER_ID NOT IN 
  (
    select 
      USER_ID 
    from signin_details 
    where 
      signin_details.PROVIDER=s1.PROVIDER 
      and signin_details.OPERATION='SIGN_UP' 
      and signin_details.TIMESTAMP/1000 BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()) * 1000
  )  
  AND OPERATION='SIGN_IN' group by PROVIDER;
```

Explain Output:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table          | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+--------------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | s1             | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | signin_details | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    6 | Using where                 |
+----+--------------------+----------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Query Output :

```
+--------------+----------+
| signin_count | PROVIDER |
+--------------+----------+
|            1 | FaceBook |
|            2 | Yahoo    |
+--------------+----------+
```

It takes more than 40 minutes to execute for 200k rows.

My assumption is it will check each row with total number of dependant subquery output.

My Assumption on this query.

```
 A -> Dependant Outputs (B,C,D) .
 A check with B
 A check with C
 A check with D
```

If dependant query output is larger it will take so long time to execute. How to improve this query?

Comment: You essentially asked the same question 4 days ago and my answer was to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`. Did you try that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305066/performace-lag-in-mysql-query/12305168#12305168

Comment: can you display `show create table......`?

Comment: Hi Walker,

I tried that , no time gained . Exactly same time taken for IN , NOT Exists .

Comment: Hi jcho360 ,
I added show create table  output.

Comment: can you add index to your table?

Comment: @jcho360 , We are in production .This table contains over 20 to 30 million rows . Adding index might be taking some more time . If a index is dropped this will prone to slave quit.

Comment: @RBK sorry to heard that, but I think that you'll need to add some INDEX to speed up your queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use **MySQL** you have to know that sub queries performs awful slow.

`IN` is slow...

`EXISTS` is often faster then `IN`

`JOIN` is mostly the fastest way do things like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  s1.PROVIDER,
  COUNT(DISTINCT s1.USER_ID)

FROM 
  signin_details s1
  LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      USER_ID, PROVIDER
    FROM 
      signin_details 
    WHERE
      signin_details.OPERATION='SIGN_UP' 
      AND 
        signin_details.TIMESTAMP 
          BETWEEN 
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000 
            AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()) * 1000
  ) AS t USING  (USER_ID, PROVIDER)

WHERE
  t.USER_ID IS NULL
  AND OPERATION='SIGN_IN'
GROUP BY s1.PROVIDER
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/122ac/12

*NOTE: If you wonder about the sqlfiddle result consider here is a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` in the query.*

Result:

```
| PROVIDER | COUNT(DISTINCT S1.USER_ID) |
-----------------------------------------
| FaceBook |                          1 |
|    Yahoo |                          2 |
```

MySQL and the `INTERSECT` story. You get all combinations of `USER_ID` and `PROVIDER` which you don't want to count. Then `LEFT JOIN` them to your data. Now all the rows you want to count have no values from the `LEFT JOIN`. You get them by `t.USER_ID IS NULL`.

---

Input:

```
| rn° | USER_ID | PROVIDER | OPERATION |     TIMESTAMP |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1   |     120 |   Google |   SIGN_UP | 1347296347000 | -
| 2   |     120 |   Google |   SIGN_IN | 1347296347000 | - (see rn° 1)
| 3   |     121 |    Yahoo |   SIGN_IN | 1347296347000 | Y
| 4   |     122 |    Yahoo |   SIGN_IN | 1347296347000 | Y
| 5   |     120 |   Google |   SIGN_UP | 1347296347000 | -
| 6   |     120 | FaceBook |   SIGN_IN | 1347296347000 | F
| 7   |     119 | FaceBook |   SIGN_IN | 1347296347000 | - (see rn° 8)
| 8   |     119 | FaceBook |   SIGN_UP | 1347296347000 | -
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use "NOT IN" inside the HAVING clause.
>     it will be faster than "where not in"